# Is there a way to manage Final Cut project files under Linux or Windows?

Tags: windows, final-cut-pro, linux

I don't have a x86 Mac at hand I'm having trouble organising a large collection of Final Cut 7 projects.

I have tried to run Final Cut under Virtualized OS X.  But I have trouble installing it since VMWare doesn't provide QuartzExtreme driver.

Is there any way to solve the issue or this is hopeless and I need a real Mac?

Comment: you could try dual booting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit FCP project files on Linux for sure. Sorry :)